# DataBinding is binding the data only at startup

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I know that for custom properties i need to use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and others, but why for a simple property:

```
public int CustomIndex {get; set; }
```

and...

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="pbGenerationProgress" Maximum="43" Value="{Binding CustomIndex}"/>
```

the progress is updated only at startup (for example if i change the CustomIndex value in the window constructor)?

I need to use always the `InvokePropertyChanged` event?

I use a simple `this.DataContext = this` for the data context.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to notify for each and every change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you always need to implement the interface and invoke the `InvokePropertyChanged` method.

That is the only way the UI can get notified about the change.

You're assumption that you need to use INofityPropertyChanged for custom properties is correct. `CustomIndex` is a custom property though.

Example:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int _customIndex;
    public int CustomIndex
    {
         get 
         {
             return _customIndex;
         }
         set 
         {
             _customIndex = value;
             if(PropertyChanged != null)
                 PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CustomIndex"));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a simple example? Thank you

Comment: I'm in a user controle and InvokePropertyChanged method is not found. Why?